# How to combine OpenCV + Tesseract?

Tags: c++, opencv, window, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to create a bot to recognize text in an inactive window.  To do this, I capture each frame using Bitmap. And I want Tesseract to scan the text (if there is one) on this frame and display it on the screen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>


#include <tesseract/capi.h>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>


using namespace cv;


Mat getMat(HWND hwnd) {
HDC deviceContext = GetDC(hwnd);
HDC memoryDeviceContext = CreateCompatibleDC(deviceContext);

RECT windowRect;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &windowRect);

int height = 500; /// windowRect.bottom windowRect.right
int width = 500;

HBITMAP bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(deviceContext, width, height);

SelectObject(memoryDeviceContext, bitmap);

// Copy data into bitmap
BitBlt(memoryDeviceContext, 0, 0, width, height, deviceContext, 750, 359, SRCCOPY);

// Spesify format by using bitmapinfoheader
BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bi.biWidth = width;
bi.biHeight = -height;
bi.biPlanes = 1;
bi.biBitCount = 32;
bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bi.biSizeImage = 0; // No compression
bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 1;
bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 2;
bi.biClrUsed = 3;
bi.biClrImportant = 4;

Mat mat = Mat(height, width, CV_8UC4); // 8 bit unsigned ints 4 channels -> RGBA

// Transform data and store into mat.data
GetDIBits(memoryDeviceContext, bitmap, 0, height, mat.data, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

// Clean up
DeleteObject(bitmap);
DeleteDC(memoryDeviceContext);
ReleaseDC(hwnd, deviceContext);

return mat;
}


int main() {
LPCWSTR windowTitle = L"Discord";
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, windowTitle);
/// String outText, imPath = argv[1];

/// tesseract::TessBaseAPI* temp = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();

std::cout << "Start" << "\n";
while (true) {
    Mat temp = getMat(hwnd);
    cv::imshow("output", temp);
    cv::waitKey(2);
}

std::cout << "Done\n";

return 1;
}
```

My attempts were unsuccessful:

```
    while (true) {
    Mat temp = getMat(hwnd);
    cv::imshow("output", temp);
    cv::waitKey(2);
    String outText, imPath = argv[1];
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI* temp = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread((const unsigned char*)temp);
    ocr->Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_LSTM_ONLY);
    ocr->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_AUTO);
    ocr->SetImage(img);
    outText = String(ocr->GetUTF8Text());
    }
```

Another attempt

```
    while (true) {
    Mat temp = getMat(hwnd);
    cv::imshow("output", temp);
    cv::waitKey(2);

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI* ocr = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    char* outText;

    ocr->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_AUTO);
    ocr->Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_LSTM_ONLY);

    ocr->SetImage(temp, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    outText = ocr->GetUTF8Text();

    ocr->End();
    delete ocr;
    return outText;
    }
```

I just want every frame from Bitmap to be scanned for the presence of text. And this text was displayed. I will be glad of any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just google for it. e.g. blogpost [OpenCV and tesseract](https://bucket401.blogspot.com/2021/04/opencv-and-tesseract.html) or example in [tesseract doc](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/examples/OpenCV_example.cc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my idea is to constantly get a picture from the screen, updating it. At the same time, the text will be read in real time. I don't understand how to do it, via "Mat". 

`std::string outText, imPath = temp;
  cv::Mat im = cv::imread(imPath, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
  tesseract::TessBaseAPI* api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
  api->Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_LSTM_ONLY);
  api->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_AUTO);
  api->SetImage(im.data, im.cols, im.rows, 3, im.step);
  outText = std::string(api->GetUTF8Text());
  std::cout << outText;
  api->End();`

Comment: Something like that, but it's python. Where `screenshot` is getting an image (Bitmap).
`text = pytesseract.image_to_string(screenshot)`